# Program still closing regardless of end clause (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a program to generate primes up to a limit; it works, but whenever I launch the program itself, which opens in the Python command line, it closes the second it finishes running. I added

```
print('Press enter to exit.')
```

at the end of the program and in other programs this stops it from closing, but this one closes anyway.
The program in full:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
def isprime(n):
    x = 2
    while(x >= 2 and x <= n**0.5):
        if n%x == 0:
            return False
        x += 1
    return True
print('Enter an upper bound.')
y = input()
print('Would you like place numbers? Y/N')
b = raw_input()
if b == 'Y' or b == 'y':
    a = 0
elif b == 'N' or b == 'n':
    a = 1
else:
    print('Error. Enter Y or N.')
i = 2
c = 1
while(a == 1 and i <= y):
    if isprime(i) == True:
        print(i)
        c += 1
    i += 1
while(a == 0 and i <= y):
     if isprime(i) == True:
        print('Prime number ' + str(c) + '-->' + str(i))
        c += 1
     i += 1
print(str(c) + ' primes in total were generated between 0 and' + str(y))
print('Press enter to exit.')
```

Note: I'd rather you help me stop it closing.

Comment: There is nothing keeping the program from not ending. Simply doing `print('Press enter to exit.')` does not block. You want to use `raw_input` there instead.

Comment: By which you mean?

Comment: Change `print('Press enter to exit.')` to `raw_input('Press enter to exit.)`

Comment: I copy pasted your code, changed that one line and it works. Don't know what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python "print" function displays text, but do not stop program execution.
So the interpreter print this line, but just after the program stops because there is no more instructions.

And on many OS, when command line program is finished, the console window is immediately closed.

But effectively, if you write instead `raw_input("press enter to exit")` , it won't close, because the "input" function waits user input, so the program is paused until the user press enter. 
I hope it answered the question

`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

`input("Press enter to exit")`

not `print(...)`

Comment: Python 2 should use `raw_input`